# MSAL for android without using chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, oauth-2.0, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

I want to integrate one drive(personal and business) and for this i am using msal.
I found that it requires chrome. I want in my application without using chrome(like popup or in app UI).

I am using this library for authentication(`msal`)
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android

Is there any solution available for android native

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to pass user credentials to the MSAL library without opening Chrome... or any other browser the user has configured as default browser for the browser Intent?

Comment: I am asking without using chrome only.

Answer (score 2):

The release of MSAL.Android 0.2.0 includes:

> Support for all major browsers on Android

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/wiki/Migrating-from-MSAL.Android-0.1.n-to-0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The MSAL library requires a browser that supports custom tabs. Chrome does. The [code comments from the MSAL AuthenticationActivity class](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/blob/dev/msal/src/main/java/com/microsoft/identity/client/AuthenticationActivity.java) tell us that the activity will launch only if Chrome is installed. Otherwise an exception is thrown. The library is open source so you can fork the repository and modify the AuthenticationActivity class to suit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your code link. I'll look into that. For now I have fixed my problem using simple webview.

Comment: @Manmohan how did you achieve this ? Did u modify the code to use your webview ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille i loaded the authentication url in webview which worked for me.

Comment: @Manmohan: And how did u get the access token back? Does this way handle mfa accounts too ?

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille by checking the url..url contains access token information in it. Yes, according to me they must be handling it same way.

Comment: @Manmohan, do u have a working demo of this? I am not able to understand where i might need to add the client id that we generate if we simply have to use the url in our custom webview.

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille I'll add some code which will help you definitely.

Comment: @Manmohan: Sure that would help. Thanks

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille I have added my ans. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I loaded below url using webview -

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=your_client_id&scope=offline_access+Files.ReadWrite+profile+openid+User.ReadBasic.All&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri&prompt=login&response_type=code

this will return code

which should use for getting the access token as below -

```
 private void requestForGetAccessToken(String code) {
    try {

        String bodyForAccessTokenRequest = getBodyForAccessTokenRequest(code);
         private static final String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";
         private static final String URL_FOR_TOKEN = "oauth2/v2.0/token/" 
        URL mUrl = new URL(AUTHORITY + URL_FOR_TOKEN);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "" + bodyForAccessTokenRequest.length());
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        httpConnection.setReadTimeout(100000);

        OutputStream os = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(bodyForAccessTokenRequest);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        httpConnection.connect();

        int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            String strRes = sb.toString();
            sendCode(strRes);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.e("[OneDrivePersonalLoginManager][requestForGetAccessToken] IOException " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.e("[OneDrivePersonalLoginManager][requestForGetAccessToken] Exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


 private String getBodyForAccessTokenRequest(String code) {
    return CLIENT_ID_EQUAL + CLIENT_ID + appendAmpersand() + appendRedirectUri() + appendAmpersand() + CODE_EQUAL + code + appendAmpersand() + GRANT_TYPE_EQUAL + AUTHORIZATION_CODE;
}
```

Response of this POST request will return access token.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still encountering this problem, the current version of MSAL for Android allows you to use a `WebView` instead of the browser. If you used the same implementation as the sample app which uses an `auth_config.json` file for your app configuration, just change the authorization user agent as a webview.

**auth_config.json**

```
{
  "client_id" : "<CLIENT_ID_FROM_https://apps.dev.microsoft.com>",
  "authorization_user_agent" : "WEBVIEW", 
  "redirect_uri" : "<CLIENT_ID_FROM_https://apps.dev.microsoft.com>://auth",
  "authorities" : [
   {
      "type": "AAD",
      "audience": {
         "type": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"
       }
   }
 ]
}
```

You wouldn't need to use the Intent filters from the previous implementation as well if you'll go this route.